# HTML I cannot load up image?

Tags: html, image

My image wont load up on page? I am not sure what is going on here, i have made many websites uptil now, but I think i made a mistake in my code. I am trying to load up this image, but it wont! :c

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
 <head>
  <title>Error 404</title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>Oops!</h1>
  <p>What you have just encountered is Error 404. This means that the page you were trying was not found. Try checking the <abbr title="Uniform Resource Locator">URL</abbr> for any mistakes. Even a small typo counts.</p>
  <p>If that doesn't work, we have provided a map of the site below. Click on anyone of the pages and you will be magically directed there.</p>
  <?php
   include 'sitemap.php';
  ?>
  <hr />
  <p align="middle">Your IP address is <?php echo $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; ?>. You are visiting <b>danishhumair.base.pk</b>.</p>
  <a href="advertisement.php"><img src="advertisement.png" /></a>
 </body>
</html>
```

I can show you a picture of my files too.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What does your network tab tell you?

Comment: Network tab? I am not sure what that is :c

Comment: May be the image is corrupted. Check another image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using Adblock try to disable it and reload the page, with that name, any advertisement block extension will stop the image from loading.

Comment: it worked O.o thanks so much :D Sadly i cant useful your answer because of my negative reputation here, but thanks! :3

Answer (score 1):

Browser problem see extensions

Comment: Thanks for the reply! :)